# On a naked chicken (skin on, but no coating, batter) is there any benefit of double frying?

Tags: chicken, frying, deep-frying, confit

So I have stumbled upon a recipe on seriouseats about double frying chicken wings in this case to get it to the most crispy buffalo wings possible. It makes me think will it helps with getting “ayam goreng” chicken legs and breast, which is traditionally cooked without any coating or batter (just marinated beforehand) to be the most crispy and juicy possible. Seriouseats mentioned to “confit” it first for 225-250F for 20 minutes and then letting it cool before final frying it at 375-400F for about 10 minutes.

Comment: When you said naked I was thinking about chicken without the skin, for which it would probably not work well. But with skin on it's probably what's on Sneftel's answer.

Comment: Naked chicken??

Comment: Caution! Authentic Buffalo wings are not crispy.  You've been warned.

Comment: @JimmyJames For someone not in the know, what does this mean?

Comment: @Onyz Could you be more specific as to what you are asking?

Comment: @JimmyJames Why are authentic buffalo wings not crispy?

Comment: @Onyz Because they aren't made that way?  It sounds a little disgusting, honestly.  Like something you'd get at KFC.

Comment: @JimmyJames I'm not sure what you mean still. I did a quick google search for 'authentic buffalo wings' and the "original recipe" in the first link explicitly specifies that the wings are deep fried until crispy.

Comment: @Onyz There could be a little big of crispiness around the edges but it's not the main attraction.  If you are going through extra effort to make the whole thing crispy like a fried chicken leg, I think you are missing the point.

Answer (score 22):

I believe you are referring to this article? https://www.seriouseats.com/2012/01/the-food-lab-how-to-make-best-buffalo-wings-fry-again-ultimate-crispy-deep-fried-buffalo-wings.html

Funny enough, I was reading this yesterday. And if you go through the end, Kenji gives a very scientific explanation on how double-frying your wings can make them more crispy.

Basically, frying first in a 250°F will melt the colagen in the skin, transforming into a gelatin and adding a ton of moisture and juiciness. Then, frying into a 400ºF oil will dehydrate the skin, making it crispy.

Answer (score 10):

It does help, yes. The first frying acts to partially dehydrate the skin, while partially hydrolysing the collagen into gelatin. The second frying then completes the dehydration and "puffing up". If you didn't have the first frying, there would be less time for those effects before the food burned.